# Node.js google maps cache

Tags: node.js, google-maps, caching

I'm creating a system designed to be run on an ad-hoc network whilst in a field with no internet, it involves displaying moving markers on a Google Map. The markers are from locations from a Node.Js websocket. Is it possible to force my server (my laptop) to cache the google maps for a specific location whilst i am in a location with wifi?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the license does not allow that.

> No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store
>   any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store
>   limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency
>   (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking
>   usage), and only if such storage: is temporary (and in no event more
>   than 30 calendar days); is secure; does not manipulate or aggregate
>   any part of the Content or Service; and does not modify attribution in
>   any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

Comment: Usually i would agree, but the data would be for improving performance, and would be temporary, as it would be collected and used within a weekend